# How to get CPU and Memory usage of nodes in a specific Kubernetes instance group?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a couple separate instance groups, and `kubectl top nodes` will display the CPU and Memory usage of all nodes. I'd like to be able to just ask for the information for a specific instance group if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Do your instance groups have labels identifying the groups they belong to? If so, you can filter to them using the `-l`/`--selector` option, like so:

```bash
kubectl top nodes --selector instance-group=group-1
```

This assumes that the label name is `instance-group` and the label value for the group you want to query is `group-1`.